# PHP loop + bidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm am trying to create a bi-dimensional array using PHP but still haven't figured it out.

```
$value = 3;

$sql = "SELECT country, capital  FROM world WHERE client = 2 ";

$myArray = array();

try {
    foreach ($connection->query($sql) as $row)
    {
        for($i=0; $i<$value; $i++){
            $myArray[$i] = array($row['country'], $row['capital']);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the function "array_push", but it's not the best way for getting a specific value.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: I'm trying to create an array inside another array, but the way I do it's not working and I want to be able to get one specific value. I don't know how to be more specific because my doubt is on the creation of a bidimensional array inside a loop.

Comment: Did you give up on this? None of these helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the for loop:

```
$sql = "SELECT country, capital  FROM world WHERE client = 2 ";

$myArray = array();

foreach ($connection->query($sql) as $row) {
   $myArray[] = array("country" => $row['country'], "capital" => $row['capital']);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping on a SINGLE result of your query. And the `for()` loop is completely unecessary:

```
$myArray = array();
foreach ($connection->query($sql) as $row)
    $myArray[] = array($row['country'], $row['capital']);
}
```

Comment: Using this way, how do I get a specific value? For example, if I want to get a 'capital'.

Comment: It's just an array. `$myArray[3][1]`

Comment: I get it now. Thank you for the tip and help :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `for` loop, and since you are specifying the columns in the query, just do this for an associative array:

```
foreach ($connection->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
    $myArray[] = $row;
}
```

Or if you want numeric index then:

```
$connection->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_NUM)
```

Or maybe you want to access something like `$myArray['England']` and get `London`?  Then build the array like so:

```
foreach ($connection->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
    $myArray[$row['country']] = $row['capital'];
}
```